# operator << must take exactly one argument

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

a.h

```
#include "logic.h"
...

class A
{
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, A&);
...
};
```

logic.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
...
ostream& logic::operator<<(ostream& os, A& a)
{
...
}
...
```

When i compile, it says:

> std::ostream& logic::operator<<(std::ostream&, A&)' must take exactly one argument.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

The problem is that you define it inside the class, which

a) means the second argument is implicit (`this`) and

b) it will not do what you want it do, namely extend `std::ostream`.

You have to define it as a free function:

```
class A { /* ... */ };
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const A& a);
```

Comment: Also, he declares it as a friend function, and defines it as a member function.

Comment: As mentioned at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators, "the overloads of operator>> and operator<< that take a std::istream& or std::ostream& as the left hand argument are known as insertion and extraction operators. Since they take the user-defined type as the right argument (b in a@b), they must be implemented as non-members".

Comment: Also if we need to print any of the private members of class A, then the `operator<<` should be implemented as a friend function in class A. 
So in this case, just as @asaelr mentioned, when defining a friend function you do not use the name of the class to scope the name of the friend function.

Comment: I also think this needs some correction.. since this is upvoted much, it would be good to correct this answer for new learners. As @user17732522 commented above.

Answer (score 58):

A friend function is not a member function, so the problem is that you declare `operator<<` as a friend of `A`:

```
 friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, A&);
```

then try to define it as a member function of the class `logic`

```
 ostream& logic::operator<<(ostream& os, A& a)
          ^^^^^^^
```

Are you confused about whether `logic` is a class or a namespace?

The error is because you've tried to define a member `operator<<` taking two arguments, which means it takes three arguments including the implicit `this` parameter. The operator can only take two arguments, so that when you write `a << b` the two arguments are `a` and `b`.

You want to define `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const A&)` as a **non**-member function, definitely not as a member of `logic` since it has nothing to do with that class!

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& a)
{
  return os << a.number;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem with templated classes.
Here's a more general solution I had to use:

```
template class <T>
class myClass
{
    int myField;

    // Helper function accessing my fields
    void toString(std::ostream&) const;

    // Friend means operator<< can use private variables
    // It needs to be declared as a template, but T is taken
    template <class U>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const myClass<U> &);
}

// Operator is a non-member and global, so it's not myClass<U>::operator<<()
// Because of how C++ implements templates the function must be
// fully declared in the header for the linker to resolve it :(
template <class U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const myClass<U> & obj)
{
  obj.toString(os);
  return os;
}
```

Now:
* My toString() function can't be inline if it is going to be tucked away in cpp.
* You're stuck with some code in the header, I couldn't get rid of it.
* The operator will call the toString() method, it's not inlined.

The body of operator<< can be declared in the friend clause or outside the class. Both options are ugly. :(

Maybe I'm misunderstanding or missing something, but just forward-declaring the operator template doesn't link in gcc.

This works too:

```
template class <T>
class myClass
{
    int myField;

    // Helper function accessing my fields
    void toString(std::ostream&) const;

    // For some reason this requires using T, and not U as above
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const myClass<T> &)
    {
        obj.toString(os);
        return os;
    }
}
```

I think you can also avoid the templating issues forcing declarations in headers, if you use a parent class that is not templated to implement operator<<, and use a virtual toString() method.

Answer (score 1):

Operator overloading includes member function overloading and non-member function overloading, which cannot be mixed. https://condor.depaul.edu/ntomuro/courses/262/notes/lecture3.html

Answer (score 0):

If you define `operator<<` as a member function it will have a different decomposed syntax than if you used a non-member `operator<<`.  A non-member `operator<<` is a binary operator, where a member `operator<<` is a unary operator.

```
// Declarations
struct MyObj;
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyObj& myObj);

struct MyObj
{
    // This is a member unary-operator, hence one argument
    MyObj& operator<<(std::ostream& os) { os << *this; return *this; }

    int value = 8;
};

// This is a non-member binary-operator, 2 arguments
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyObj& myObj)
{
    return os << myObj.value;
}
```

So.... how do you really call them?  Operators are odd in some ways, I'll challenge you to write the `operator<<(...)` syntax in your head to make things make sense.

```
MyObj mo;

// Calling the unary operator
mo << std::cout;

// which decomposes to...
mo.operator<<(std::cout);
```

Or you could attempt to call the non-member binary operator:

```
MyObj mo;

// Calling the binary operator
std::cout << mo;

// which decomposes to...
operator<<(std::cout, mo);
```

You have no obligation to make these operators behave intuitively when you make them into member functions, you could define `operator<<(int)` to left shift some member variable if you wanted to, understand that people may be a bit caught off guard, no matter how many comments you may write.

Almost lastly, there may be times where both decompositions for an operator call are valid, you may get into trouble here and we'll defer that conversation.

Lastly, note how odd it might be to write a unary member operator that is supposed to look like a binary operator (as you can make member operators virtual..... also attempting to not devolve and run down this path....)

```
struct MyObj
{
    // Note that we now return the ostream
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os) { os << *this; return os; }

    int value = 8;
};
```

This syntax will irritate many coders now....

```
MyObj mo;

mo << std::cout << "Words words words";

// this decomposes to...
mo.operator<<(std::cout) << "Words words words";

// ... or even further ...
operator<<(mo.operator<<(std::cout), "Words words words");
```

Note how the `cout` is the second argument in the chain here.... odd right?

Answer (score 0):

The key point is the `logic::` before `operator<<` which is defined as a friend function.

`logic::` is only added before the member function. I understand that this is similar to telling the compiler that this function is a member function and granting it corresponding permissions (such as accessing private functions).

In other words,  just as @asaelr and @Morteza mentioned, "when defining a friend function you do not use the name of the class to scope the name of the friend function".

Hence, we should remove `logic::` before `operator<<`.