# overloading <<, error at compile time

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

the code :

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, point p) { 
  out << "(" << p.x << ", "<< p.y<< ", "<< p.z << ")";
  return out;
}
```

the error:

> ‘std::ostream& KillThemAll::point::operator<<(std::ostream&, KillThemAll::point)’
>   must take exactly one argument
>        std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, point p) { out << "(" << p.x << ", "<< p.y<< ", "<< p.z << ")"; return out;}

actualy, the code is similar at the one p.402 of « Problems & Solutions In Scientific Computing » (except I'm using 3D instead of 2D).

for your curiosity, here the mighty structure « point » :

```
struct point{
    double x,y,z;
    point() { x=y=z=0.0;}
    point(double _x, double _y, double _z){this->x=_x, this->y=_y, this->z=_z;}
    point operator - (const point& _p) const { return point(x-_p.x, y-_p.y, z-_p.z);}
    point operator + (const point& _p) const { return point(x+_p.x, y+_p.y, z+_p.z);}
    double operator * (const point& _p) const { return x*_p.x+y*_p.y+z*_p.z;}
    point operator * (const double _t) const { return point(_t*x, _t*y, _t*z);}
    point operator / (const double _t) const { if(_t!=0) return point(x/_t, y/_t, z/_t);}
  };
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744787/operator-must-take-exactly-one-argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like you're declaring your `operator<<` as a member function in the `point` class. This is not what you want.

Instead, declare it as a free function (outside of your `point` class). If it needs to access private members of `point`, then make it a friend.

**Why?**

When you think about it, it's obvious that any `operator<<` must have exactly two arguments; one to the left of the `<<`, and one to the right. If you declare the operator in-class, then the left argument is automatically taken to be the object in question (`this`), so you can only tell it what type the right argument should have. If you declare it as a free function, then you get to choose both the left and right argument types.

Comment: ok you got the point, I didn't take care enough... I have `operator<<` in `point` (wich is a `struct`)... it's a mistake from me, I agree it shouldn't be there! so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should pass `point p` by const reference: `const point& p` so it isn't getting reconstructed as a new object.

secondly, you seem to be defining a `operator<<` function within `class KillThemAll` this is not legal overloading for stream output/input; you must define it as a free and, if it needs to access private members, friend function.

Comment: Or as a `friend` function.

Comment: well, as said this code comes from a book, so for the const, I'm agree with you but I just copied like it's written. I didn't heard before today that overloading << must be a free function, in the book it is, I'm using a namespace for personnal convenience. Thank you

Comment: If `point` is small and has a trivial copy constructor, it can be more efficient to pass it by value than by const reference, although obviously this depends on many factors. Also, from the look of it `KillThemAll` (!) is a namespace; the problem is that the `operator<<` is being declared in the `point` class.

Comment: @TristanBrindle, It seems to be a 3D point; initializing three float variables wouldn't be faster than passing in a const reference.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode yeah, you're right, I was just being pedantic :-) Actually, now that `point` has been posted it's actually three doubles, so a const reference would be much better!