# pass std::endl to std::operator <<

Tags: c++, std

In this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8111734/2345484)
it says that `std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;` is the same as

```
std::operator<<(std::operator<<(std::cout, "Hello World!"), std::endl);
```

But when I compile the above line code, it doesn't compile! Then after trying something else I found that the reason it doesn't compile is because of `std::endl`, if I replace `std::endl` by `"\n"` then it works. But why you can not pass `std::endl` to `std::operator<<`?

Or more simply, isn't `std::cout<<std::endl;` the same as `std::operator<<(std::cout, std::endl);`?

**EDIT**

When compile with `icpc test.cpp`, the error message is 
`error: no instance of overloaded function "std::operator<<" matches the argument list argument types are: (std::ostream, <unknown-type>) std::operator<<(std::cout, std::endl);`

and `g++ test.cpp` gives much much longer error message.

Comment: The latter question could likely be answered by just trying *that* line of code. And "...it doesn't compile!" means little unless you also include *the error message* you received when it failed to compile *in your question*.

Comment: I tried, `std::operator<<(std::cout, std::endl);` does not compile.

Comment: The overload for manipulators is a member function, so `std::cout.operator<<(std::endl)`

Comment: What's the difference of `std::operator <<` and `std::cout.operator <<`? Where do you think I can find a reference to `std::operator <<`?

Comment: @Allanqunzi It is a member function call vs a non-member function call. Similar to `print(x, "hi")` vs `x.print("hi")`. [Though operator functions are found differently](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Overloaded_operator) than other names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the answer there is a bit wrong. [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is a manipulator function, there is no overload for them in definitions of standalone [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) of `ostream`. It is a member function of [basic_ostream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).

In other word, the presented invocation is wrong. It should be one of the following:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::endl(std::operator<<(std::cout, "Hello World!"));
    std::operator<<(std::cout, "Hello World!").operator<<(std::endl);

    //of course if you pass new line as a supported type it works
    std::operator<<(std::operator<<(std::cout, "Hello World!"), '\n');
    std::operator<<(std::operator<<(std::cout, "Hello World!"), "\n");
    std::operator<<(std::operator<<(std::cout, "Hello World!"), string("\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

[Live examples.](http://ideone.com/BF0XVN)

Well, some people do say that stream library does not have the prettiest design in the standard.

Comment: What surprises me is that the first call works. Where is that defined? As a global operator in std::namespace? And even better: `operator<<(std::cout, "hello, world").operator<<(std::endl)` so that ADL finds the `std::operator`, right?

Comment: @5gon12eder Yes, I included working examples as an edit.

Comment: @5gon12eder Oh, sure. It's a habit, and the `using` is from copy-pasta from ideone standard template.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. One more question what's the difference of the `operator <<` in `ostream` and `std::operator <<`, in the question I asked it is `std::operator <<`, but in your explanation it is the `ostream::operator <<`.

Comment: @WorldSEnder I am not sure what you ask about. But I edit the answer to provide links. `operator<<(std::basic_ostream)` is defined in [`ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ostream), ADL is nicely described in the linked question and answers.

Comment: @Allanqunzi They are defined in different places. You can define nearly every operator as a member and a non-member function, but this is more general than just `operator<<`. You can read about it here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators . And here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421729/1133179 .

Comment: I wonder what the reasong behind the design choice not to include the overload for manipulators in the namespace was.

Comment: @WorldSEnder I am not sure, maybe it's worth asking on its own, what is the technical reason behind it. I am quite sure there is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about this topic, but i think these 2 questions and answers are somewhat related to your question and might help you figure out a solution

[operator << must take exactly one argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744787/operator-must-take-exactly-one-argument)

[Does std::cout have a return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987156/does-stdcout-have-a-return-value)