# operator<<(ostream&, const BigUnsigned<I>&) must take exactly one argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading

I tried to separate the declaration and definition of my templated member function of a templated class, but ended up with the following error and warning.

```
template <typename I>
class BigUnsigned{
    const size_t cell_size=sizeof(I);
    std::vector<I> _integers;
public:
    BigUnsigned();
    BigUnsigned(I);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const BigUnsigned& bu);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const BigUnsigned& bu){
    for (auto integer : bu._integers){
        out<<integer<<std::endl;
    }
    return out;
}
```

> ../hw06/bigunsigned.h:13:77: warning: friend declaration
>   'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const BigUnsigned&)'
>   declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
>        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const BigUnsigned& bu);
>                                                                                ^ ../hw06/bigunsigned.h:13:77: note: (if this is not what you
>   intended, make sure the function template has already been declared
>   and add <> after the function name here)  ../hw06/bigunsigned.h:16:51:
>   error: invalid use of template-name 'BigUnsigned' without an argument
>   list  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const BigUnsigned&
>   bu){
>                                                      ^ ../hw06/bigunsigned.h: In function 'std::ostream&
>   operator<<(std::ostream&, const int&)': ../hw06/bigunsigned.h:17:28:
>   error: request for member '_integers' in 'bu', which is of non-class
>   type 'const int'
>        for (auto integer : bu._integers){
>                               ^

When I joined the declaration and definition like this, everything compiles fine.

```
template <typename I>
class BigUnsigned{
    const size_t cell_size=sizeof(I);
    std::vector<I> _integers;
public:
    BigUnsigned();
    BigUnsigned(I);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const BigUnsigned& bu){
        for (auto integer : bu._integers){
            out<<integer<<std::endl;
        }
        return out;
    }
};
```

The purpose was to print member variable _integers to cout. What might be the problem?

P.S.: Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744787/operator-must-take-exactly-one-argument) I made the function free, but did not help.

Comment: FWIW, for _me_, it seems a little unexpected for `BigUnsigned` to be a container. Take that with the grain of salt, though.

Comment: @erip, why do you think `BigUnsigned` is a container here? `operator<<` is a formatting operator. It has nothing to do with containers.

Comment: @JanHudec No, but to store data in a `std::vector` has everything to do with containers.

Comment: @JanHudec `BigUnsigned<std::string> bu{"Hello, World"}; /* oops, not really a big unsigned after all */`

Comment: @erip, you can't get an arbitrary precision without something of arbitrary size and that something is a vector. As for using `std::string` for the parameter, presumably the methods not shown require the parameter is a numeric type.

Comment: Sure, but with a constructor of the form `BigUnsigned(I);`, I don't think this is going to be the right approach to creating an arbitrary precision object in the first place. I both digress and am happy to disagree.

Comment: One last note: with a member named `_integers`, I might expect it to be a `std::vector<int>` (maybe more appropriately `std::vector<unsigned int>`?), thus rendering all templatization useless and clearing up the wonkiness.

Comment: @erip The `BigUnsigned(I)` constructor is clearly a nonesense. I will overload the constructors for each integer data type eventually. As for the typename `I`, the valid values are all the primitive integer types (unsigned char, unsigned int, unsigned short, etc.). Later I might even allow signet types. How to check if `I` is an allowed type when using only a single templated class? Using `typeid` in constructors?

Comment: @Slazer Try [`std::is_integral`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_integral/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BigUnsigned` is a template type so

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const BigUnsigned& bu)
```

Will not work as there is no `BigUnsigned`.  You need to make the friend function a template so you can take different types of `BigUnsigned<some_type>`s.

```
template <typename I>
class BigUnsigned{
    const size_t cell_size=sizeof(I);
    std::vector<I> _integers;
public:
    BigUnsigned();
    BigUnsigned(I);
    template<typename T>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const BigUnsigned<T>& bu);
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const BigUnsigned<T>& bu){
    for (auto integer : bu._integers){
        out<<integer<<std::endl;
    }
    return out;
}
```

The reason the second example works is that since it is declared inside the class it uses the template type that the class uses.

Comment: @Slazer, actually, you _don't_ want to make the `template <typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const BigUnsigned<T>&)` a friend of `BigUnsigned<I>` for unrelated `I` and `T`, so you _don't_ want to prefix the friend declaration with `typename`. You only need to prefix the out-of-class definition; see R Sahu's answer.

Answer (score 4):

A refinement to [the answer by NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34928161/434551).

With the other answer, all instantiations of the function template are `friend`s of all instatiations of the class template.

`operator<< <int>` is a `friend` of `BigUnsigned<int>` as well as `BigUnsigned<double>`.

`operator<< <double>` is a `friend` of `BigUnsigned<double>` as well as `BigUnsigned<FooBar>`.

You can change the declarations a little bit so that

`operator<< <int>` is a `friend` of `BigUnsigned<int>` but not of `BigUnsigned<double>`.

`operator<< <double>` is a `friend` of `BigUnsigned<double>` but not `BigUnsigned<FooBar>`.

```
// Forward declaration of the class template.
template <typename I> class BigUnsigned;

// Forward declaration of the function template
template <typename I>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const BigUnsigned<I>& bu);

// Change the friend-ship declaration in the class template.
template <typename I>
class BigUnsigned{
    const size_t cell_size=sizeof(I);
    std::vector<I> _integers;
public:
    BigUnsigned();
    BigUnsigned(I);

    // Grant friend-ship only to a specific instantiation of the
    // function template.
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <I>(std::ostream& out, const BigUnsigned<I>& bu);
};
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the possibility to define the friend function inline?

Comment: @phresnel, do you mean defining it inside the definition of `BigUnsigned`?

Comment: Yeah, sure, sometimes this makes things more maintainable.

Comment: @phresnel, you cannot implement the `operator<<` function inside the class template definition with my suggestion. It has to be implemented outside.

Comment: I just realise you were defining a free template function, too. Of course you are right; I'll add my solution as another answer.

Comment: @RSahu You probably have a typo. The `BigUnsigned<T>` should be `BigUnsigned<I>`, otherwise it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

To add a third variant that improves the readability a little bit, is to define the friend function inside the class:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Foo {
    int test = 42;

    // Note: 'Foo' inside the class body is basically a shortcut for 'Foo<T>'
    // Below line is identical to: friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, Foo<T> const &foo)
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, Foo const &foo) {
        return os << foo.test;
    }
};


int main () {
    Foo<int> foo;
    std::cout << foo << '\n';
}
```