# operator<< must take exactly one argument

Tags: c++

I have an error with the class i wrote and i dont understad what is the problem.

this is worker class:

```
#ifndef __Worker__
#define __Worker__

#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

class Worker{
    protected:
        std::string name;
        int id;
        int salary;

    public:
        Worker(const std::string& name, int id, int salary);
        Worker(const Worker& worker );
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Worker& w);
        int getWorkerID(){
            return this->id;
        }
        int getsSalary(){
            return this->salary;
        }
        std::string getname(){
            return this->name;
        }

};
#endif
```

and this is the implemention of this class:

```
#include "Worker.hpp"

Worker::Worker(const std::string &names, int ids, int salarys) :
name(names), id(ids), salary(salarys)
{
}

Worker::Worker(const Worker &worker): 
name(worker.name), id(worker.id), salary(worker.salary)
{

}


std::ostream& Worker::operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Worker& w)  
{  
    os << "worker name:" << w.getname() << " id:" << std::to_string(w.getWorkerID()) << " salary:"<<std::to_string(w.getsSalary()) ;  
    return os;  
}
```

some one can tell me please what worng with operator<< that i wrote?

Comment: A friend is not a member, so just remove the `Worker::` prefix.

Comment: s/`Worker::operator<<`/`operator<<`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [operator << must take exactly one argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744787/operator-must-take-exactly-one-argument)

Comment: Unrelated to your question and problem, but symbols beginning with two underscores (like `__Worker__`) are reserved in all scopes. Please read [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for more details.

Comment: @BoPersson I removed the "Worker::" and it still not work.

Comment: @EliorSastiel: Yes, it still doesn't work, but the error message will be completely different! Please don't neglect to mention such an important fact when you say that it "still doesn't work". My answer explains how to fix those other errors as well.

Answer (score 8):

This line in your implementation code:

> ```
> std::ostream& Worker::operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Worker& w)
> ```

Should be:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Worker& w)
```

That's because `Worker::operator<<` would be a member function, not a non-member friend function as you correctly declare it in the header file, and if it's a member function, then error message means exactly what it means.

Once you've fixed this error, you will find out that further errors appear, because your getter member functions aren't `const`. Another error to be fixed is the `__Worker__` macro. A name like that is reserved for the implementation, and it's strange to have a macro with lowercase letters in its name; make it something like `WORKER_H`.