# Input/Output Operators Overloading, must take exactly one argument error

Tags: c++, overloading

First I declared my overloaded function similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10744787/11608028) and had the same error as there. I changed as the answer suggest, but still got this error:

> [Error] 'std::ostream& Number::operator<<(std::ostream&, const Number&)' must take exactly one argument

Code:

```
    //numb.hpp   
    class Number {   
        public:
        .....    
        std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const Number&);  
    }；  

    //numb.cpp  
    std::ostream& Number::operator<<(std::ostream &output, const Number &Num){
                output << "The integers this object stores are: " << Num.num << " and " << Num.num1;
                return output; 
             }
```

Comment: Overloading operators as member functions or non-member functions sometimes means different things. In your case you should not overload it as a member function. Please go through your books, tutorials or class-notes again. Or perhaps [get a couple of new good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Answer (score 0):

What you have there are two different declarations - first one declares a global overloaded operator, the second one declares (and defines) an operator that's a *member* of class `Number` (notice the `Number::`?). First one is OK (if that's what your intention is - to define it as a free standing operator), second one is obviously not. As explained is the answer you linked and as the error says -  member operators need to take *one* argument (besides the implicit `this` argument).

Comment: i have edited the question, i forgot to mention that my overloaded function is within class Number, it is not global oveloaded operator

Comment: Except that it will not work. What I assume you want is `cout << num;` where `num` is type `Number`. You *need* a free standing operator overload.