# Expected class name error, inheritance in C++

Tags: c++

I have two classes in C++ - Vector and VectorFile (which inherits from Vector class). While creating VectorFile class I got error: Expected class name, so the compiler can't see Vector class in VectorFile.h, although I have included it.

VectorFile.h:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Vector.h"
using namespace std;
class VectorFile : public Vector{
public:
    ostream &operator << (ostream &output, Vector &V);
    istream &operator >> (istream &input, Vector &V);
};
```

Vector.h:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename type>
class Vector{
protected:
    type *data;
    size_t allocatedDataSize;
    size_t usingDataSize{};
public:
   
    Vector();
    Vector(size_t usingDataSize);
    ~Vector();
};
```

Comment: You have `class VectorFile : public Vector { ...` but `Vector` *isn't* a class -- it's a class template.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `using namespace std;` is a bad idea and especial problematic if you use it in a header file.

Comment: Imagine doing `#include <vector>`, and then defining a variable `std::vector v{};`. What's missing?

Comment: @t.niese can you please  elaborate  why is it so?

Comment: Re. `using namespace std;` please see ["Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 2):

As your `Vector` is a template and not a class, you have to give the type for your Vector to make it a class template instance.

```
class VectorFile : public Vector< put your type here >{
```

Maybe `VectorFile` itself will becomes a template if needed:

```
template < typename T>
class VectorFile : public Vector< T >{
```

From your comment:

> and then defining a variable std::vector v{};. What's missing

The same as before! As your `Vector` is a template, you have to give the template parameters to get a template instance which is a type itself. You can define variables only from types, not from templates.

```
std::vector<int> v{};
```

If you use C++20, the template parameter can automatically deduced from given values to the constructor. As an example, if you provide some values for a `std::vector`, the template automatically instantiates for that type:

```
std::vector v{1,2,3};
```

In this case, you have `std::vector<int>`

In addition, you can also write `user defined deduction guides`... but this is the next question :-)

Answer (score 0):

`VectorFile` inherits from a template class, so it must also be a template class.

```
template<typename type>
class VectorFile : public Vector<type>{
public:
    ostream &operator << (ostream &output, Vector<type> &V);
    istream &operator >> (istream &input, Vector<type> &V);
};
```

This code will have another error: "error: ‘std::ostream& VectorFile::operator<<(std::ostream&, Vector&)’ must have exactly one argument". I did not fix this because it's not obvious whether you want to give `Vector` or `VectorFile` as the argument.

See this question for instructions how to fix it: [operator << must take exactly one argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744787/operator-must-take-exactly-one-argument)

Comment: `Vector` is a class template (not a template class)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: Yes, but `Vector<type>` is not a class template and could more accurately be described as a [template] class.